# Do we have any site that deals with ASReml questions?

Tags: discussion, site-proposal

Is there any <s>forum</s> site such as Stack Overflow where questions regarding ASReml can be asked to a wide cross-section of experts in that field?

Answer (score 2):

I see from the [ASReml](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASReml) Wikipedia page that:

> ASReml is a statistical software package for fitting linear mixed models using restricted maximum likelihood, a technique commonly used in plant and animal breeding and quantitative genetics as well as other fields.

We don't have anything that tightly focused, but you might try your questions on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), the Stack Exchange site for questions on statistical analysis.